# Jasmine gulp plugin

Tags: jasmine, gulp

I cannot quite figure out how can I use gulp with jasmine. I installed and configured it, so it runs my tests, but I am not sure how to introduce my javascript files to jasmine without the jasmin runner html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `gulp-jasmine`?

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src('spec/test.js').pipe(jasmine());
});
```

The `src()` method can take a glob like `'spec/**/*.js'` and automatically run jasmine on all javascript files in the spec directory.